# How do i include a custom phtml file in the list view?

Tags: layout, catalog, magento-1

This is the content from my `layout.xml`:

```
<catalog_category_view>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="mynamespace_mymodule/types_listview"  name="impressions" template="mynamespace/mymodule/listview.phtml"/>
    </reference>
<catalog_category_view>
```

The content of the `listview.phtml` is just a text. I want my custom text to be displayed in the list view. How can I achieve that?

Comment: use `after="-"` and clear you cache too..

Comment: @QaisarSatti, nope, doesn't work.

Comment: also you need to add `catalog_category_default` because your code will not work of the category is `Non-anchor`

Comment: See here its work for me i hope its work for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290378/magento-call-custom-phtml-in-list-phtml-via-xml

Answer (score 0):

you tag is not properly closed `</catalog_category_default>` use reference `catalog_category_layered` or `catalog_category_default`

```
<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="mynamespace_mymodule/types_listview"  name="impressions"  template="mynamespace/mymodule/listview.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

or try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23261274/adding-a-block-to-magento-category-page-using-local-xml)